# how to edit execution context for a job in junit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-batch, powermockito

I am able to launch a job from joblaunchertestutils and pass job parameters. I want to pass executioncontext too. something like this but its not working

```
@MockBean
JobExecution jobExecution;

@MockBean
ExecutionContext executionContext ;

@MockBean
DownloadDecider downloadDecider;

@MockBean
StepExecution stepExecution;

@BeforeAll
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    
    when(jobExecution.getExecutionContext()).thenReturn(this.executionContext);
    when(jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get(BatchRESULTS)).thenReturn("src/test/r");
```

@Test
public void testJob() throws Exception {

```
    JobParameters params1 = new JobParameters(setJobParams());
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
    
    
}
```

@Component("DownloadDecider")
public class DownloadDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadDecider.class);

@Override
public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
    
    System.out.println(stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    System.out.println(jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get(BatchRESULTS));
```

//prints null . the value is not passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mocking setup is incorrect here:

```
when(jobExecution.getExecutionContext()).thenReturn(this.executionContext);
when(jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get(BatchRESULTS)).thenReturn("src/test/r");
```

You need to first mock the behaviour you need from the execution context, then set it on the job execution:

```
when(this.executionContext.get(BatchRESULTS)).thenReturn("src/test/r");
when(jobExecution.getExecutionContext()).thenReturn(this.executionContext);
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud.That was helpful